# Can you help me find the datasheet of this IC marked LD5762WGR 2130DY?

Tags: power, ac, power-electronics, identification

This IC is a used IC on a power board.

Can you help me find the datasheet?

[image]

Comment: It looks like it might have only seven pins; is that correct? There are only a handful of devices in a package like that with only seven pins, and it'd narrow it down a lot if so. Also, what's the spacing between the pins? Is it 0.1 inch, or 0.05 inch?

Comment: yes 7 pin
0.05 inch between pins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The markings and packaging match this PWM controller: [Leadtrend LD5762WGR](https://www.leadtrend.com.tw/images/cgcustom/img020201217153628.pdf).